# How do interpret $x \lambda y . \lambda z . x$?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am not sure how to interpret this term. My first thought is that it is this an application of $x$ to $\lambda y.\lambda z.x$ Is that the correct interpretation or is it not reducible?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context on your notation?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. @DominikS This is lambda calculus which is standard notation in the theory of computation and the foundation of functional programming languages like Haskell or Scala.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, the only possible parsing of this expression is “$x$ applied to $λy.λz.x$”. In general, standard conventions for writing λ-terms are the usual “Barendregt” one, or the [Krivine notation](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38894/krivines-notation-for-lambda-terms). One should make clear the notation they use when writing λ-terms.

By the way, be careful with the words you are using:

- to *interpret* a λ-term is something else, it usually refers to giving it a semantics in a model;
- this term is *not* reducible, at least for the standard notion of reduction (aka. β-reduction), since it does not contain any β-redex.